# In Application Messaging in NodeJS Application

Tags: node.js, push-notification, messaging, pusher, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to implement in-app messaging (Message center Module) for my web application which will send and receive messages between users of the system.
I am using NodeJS as my backend.

I am planning to use PUSH notifications for this. With this approach, I can send push notifications for each new messages to the users. This is the simplest solution I can think of.

But there might be already a readymade service or library present for this problem as this seems very general scenario. 
I am already evaluating Twilio, Sendbird, Smooch, Pusher and many other libraries but the problem with them is either they are email services or Text SMS services which is not what I want. I don't want to send an SMS or Email to users.

So as of now, PUSH notifications is what I can think of, to implement simple in-app messaging service.

If there is any better way or any library available to help this, then please do suggest.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked in 2018, not sure what the state was back then but Twilio has support for in-app chat (called Programmable Chat), and even a successor called Twilio Conversations, that allows for different transport/channel mechanisms - one conversation over SMS and/or WhatsApp and/or in-app-chat... SendBird for sure allows in-app chat without any reliance on email, and supports [push notifications](https://docs.sendbird.com/ios/push_notifications).

Interesting alternative would be an open-source SDK backed by a Firebase account you own: https://chatsdk.co or https://www.chat21.org.

Answer (score 0):

For notification I think you can use firebase / onesignal / push notification. As for message between client , If it is chat you could use socket.io for this. ( If you need scaling you might need message queuing as well. )